# How does swapping of members in tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?

Tags: python, tuples, python-internals, iterable-unpacking

```
In [55]: a = 5

In [56]: b = 6

In [57]: (a, b) = (b, a)

In [58]: a
Out[58]: 6

In [59]: b
Out[59]: 5
```

How does this swapping of values of a and b work internally? Its definitely not using a temp variable.

Comment: It may interest you to view the disassembly of your code with [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). Spoliers: the bytecode instruction [`ROT_TWO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) is used.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Python separates the right-hand side expression from the left-hand side assignment. First the right-hand side is evaluated, and the result is stored on the stack, and then the left-hand side names are assigned using opcodes that take values *from* the stack again.

For tuple assignments with 2 or 3 items, Python just uses the stack directly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     a, b = b, a
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

After the two [`LOAD_FAST` opcodes](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST) (which push a value from a variable onto the stack), the top of stack holds `[a, b]`. The [`ROT_TWO` opcode](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) swaps the top two positions on the stack so the stack now has `[b, a]` at the top. The two [`STORE_FAST` opcodes](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) then takes those two values and store them in the names on the left-hand side of the assignment. The first `STORE_FAST` pops a value of the top of the stack and puts it into `a`, the next pops again, storing the value in `b`. The rotation is needed because Python guarantees that assignments in a target list on the left-hand side are done from left to right.

For a 3-name assignment, [`ROT_THREE`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_THREE) followed by `ROT_TWO` is executed to reverse the top three items on the stack.

For longer left-hand-side assignments, an explicit tuple is built:

```
>>> def bar(a, b, c, d):
...     d, c, b, a = a, b, c, d
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              9 LOAD_FAST                3 (d)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             15 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (d)
             21 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             27 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here the stack with `[d, c, b, a]` is used to build a tuple (in reverse order, [`BUILD_TUPLE`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_TUPLE) pops from the stack again, pushing the resulting tuple onto the stack), and then [`UNPACK_SEQUENCE`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-UNPACK_SEQUENCE) pops the tuple from the stack again, pushes all elements back from the tuple back onto the stack again for the `STORE_FAST` operations.

The latter may seem like a wasteful operation, but the right-hand side of an assignment may be something entirely different, a function call that *produces* a tuple perhaps, so the Python interpreter makes no assumptions and uses the `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` opcode always. It does so even for the two and three-name assignment operations, [but a later (peephole) optimization step](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/85e415108226cc5f3fdddd70196fc4c2a1d0f7f4/Python/peephole.c#L323-L351) replaces a `BUILD_TUPLE` / `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` combination with 2 or 3 arguments with the above `ROT_TWO` and `ROT_THREE` opcodes for efficiency.

Comment: +1 for **The rotation is needed because Python guarantees that assignments in a target list on the left-hand side are done from left to right.**. I did not know that.

Comment: What's the ELI5 of this explanation?

Comment: Can we relate the two values stored on the stack as if they are two temporary variables? I know may not be technically correct, but just for understanding sake

Comment: @JoeTheShmoe: if you are 5, I'd say: Python does some complicated juggling to get everything in the right place (and perhaps, if I could, juggle some balls to demonstrate. Juggling is just as complicated until you get the hang of it, and a 5-year-old would most likely be very impressed, whether I can juggle or not).

Comment: @SreenikethanI: the stack is basically *all* temporary variables, so yes. The stack is like a scratch-pad for Python to do what it does.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! For reference, here's the [C code for `ROT_TWO`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.16/Python/ceval.c#L1510), at least in Python3.9. It's apparently been replaced by a more generic `SWAP` in newer versions.