# Why a, b = b, a + b is not equal to a = b, b = a + b when I running a fib() in python?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am new in python programming, and I am trying writing fib based on the generator. And I tried this:

```
def fib(n):
  a = 0
  b = 1
  for _ in range(n):
     yield a
     print(a)
     a, b = b, a + b
     print((a,b))
```

and This one:

```
def fib(n):
  a = 0
  b = 1
  for _ in range(n):
    yield a
    a = b 
    b = a + b
print(list(fib(a)))
```

the results are different, why would that happen?

Comment: Write the steps out on paper in both cases and you’ll see why. You are overwriting the value of a before using.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense. Please fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python a, b = b, a +b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990883/python-a-b-b-a-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't break this

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

into this:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Instead, Python compiler evaluates right hand of an expression first by converting this:

```
a = 0
b = 1
a, b = b, a + b
```

into this:

```
a = 0
b = 1
a, b = 1, 1
```

then assigns it in proper order.
So `a` and `b` becomes 1.

Answer (score 0):

Step through and find out!

```
a = 0
b = 1

# loop starts:                         # loop starts
yield a    # yields 0,   a=0, b=1      yield a        # yields 0,   a=0, b=1
a = b      #             a=1, b=1      a, b = b, b+a  #             a=1, b=1
b = a + b  #             a=1, b=2
# loop
yield a    # yields 1,   a=1, b=2      yield a        # yields 1,   a=1, b=1
a = b      #             a=2, b=2      a, b = b, b+a  #             a=1, b=2
b = a + b  #             a=2, b=4
# loop
yield a    # yields 2    a=2, b=4      yield a        # yields 1,   a=1, b=2
a = b      #             a=4, b=4      a, b = b, b+a  #             a=2, b=3
b = a + b  #             a=4, b=8
# etc...
```