# Could anyone please explain how the last line of the code is working. The language used in python, I am new to python?

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I am not able to understand how the last line is able to print the Fibonacci series. It will be a great help, if someone can sequentially explain the code.

```
   a , b = 0 , 1
    while b < 10:
        print(b, end = ' ')
         a, b = b, a + b
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990883/python-a-b-b-a-b Please refer to the explanation on above link.

I understood the expression. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop starts

1. a = 0 , b=1 ; b < 10

   so a, b = b, a+b is a =1 ,b = 1
2. now a= 1, b= 1 ; b< 10

   so a, b = b, a+b is 1, 2
3. now a = 1, b = 2; b < 10

   so a, b = b, a+b is 2, 3
4. now a = 2, b = 3; b < 10

   so a, b = b, a+b is 3, 5
5. now a = 3, b = 5; b < 10

   so a, b = b, a+b is 5, 8
6. now a = 5, b = 8; (b > 10)

   so a, b = b, a+b is 8, 13 ; b>10 (loop breaks)

ans is 1 1 2 3 5 8

Answer (score 2):

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Is packing a tuple `b, a + b` and unpacking it on the same line `a, b =`.

> The statement *t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'* is an example of tuple packing: the values *12345*, *54321* and *'hello!'* are packed together in a tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:
>   *x, y, z = t*
>   This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires that there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as there are elements in the sequence. **Note that multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.**

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: so...if my understanding is correct. then the aforementioned code is equivalent to
a = b & b = a + b. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: What do you mean by the '&'?

Comment: & not in coding terms but as in English literature

a = b and b = a + b

Comment: You can look like this. But keep in mind that the order of this equations doesn't matter. And it's not the same as typing a = b and then (after new line) b = a + b. Because a would have been already changed when calculating a + b.