# Switching Two Values in Dictionary, Keeping Keys Constant

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the most efficient way to switch say two values in a dictionary, so that two keys would be mapping to two different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tuple assignment:

```
d['bar'], d['foo'] = d['foo'], d['bar']
```

This simply swaps the values. The Python compiler [optimizes for such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally/21047622#21047622), and this doesn't require any frame stack pushes (provided `d` doesn't implement `__getitem__` and / or `__setitem__` hooks in Python code).

Answer (score 3):

The same way you would swap any other values:

```
my_dict[key0], my_dict[key1] = my_dict[key1], my_dict[key0]
```