# How tuples used for swapping?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How this code work? How this tuple swap the values in this code?

```
>>> list1=[1,2,3,4]
>>> (list1[0],list1[1])=(list1[1],list1[0])
>>>
```

Comment: How deep do you want to go? There's [How does swapping of members in the python tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21047524)

Comment: I re-duped this to a post about swapping list elements, but [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14836228) is also applicable, just not as specific.