# Python: setting two variable values separated by a comma in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variable-assignment

What is the difference in python between doing:

```
a, b = c, max(a, b)
```

and

```
a = c
b = max(a, b)
```

what does having the two variable assignments set on the same line do?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your two snippets do different things: try with `a`, `b` and `c` equal to `7`, `8` and `9` respectively.

The first snippet sets the three variables to `9`, `8` and `9`. In other words, `max(a, b)` is calculated *before* `a` is assigned to the value of `c`. Essentially, all that `a, b = c, max(a, b)` does is push two values onto the stack; the variables `a` and `b` are then assigned to these values when they are popped back off.

On the other hand, running the second snippet sets all three variables to `9`. This is because `a` is set to point to the value of `c` before the function call `max(a, b)` is made.

Comment: How would you rewrite the first snippet in multiple lines of code? Using a "temp" variable to hold a value I'm guessing?

Comment: @farid99: yes a temp variable would be a good way: `temp = max(a, b)` then `a = c` then `b = temp`. Alternatively, in this case you could just carefully choose the order of the two lines, e.g. `b = max(a, b)` then `a = c` should have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

They are different. The second one is like doing

```
a, b = c, max(c, b)
```

because you are assigning `c` to `a` before doing `b = max(a, b)`. While the first one is using the old value of `a` to calculate it.