# Multiple assignment with Numpy arrays and lists, a curious example

Tags: python, numpy, assignment-operator, python-internals

Consider the multiple assignment `x[0],y = y,x[0]`. Applied to each of the four below cases, this gives four different results.

- Case 1:

  ```
  x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
  y = [5,6]
  ```

  gives

  ```
  x = [[5,6], [3,4]]
  y = [1,2]
  ```
- Case 2:

  ```
  x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
  y = [5,6]
  ```

  gives

  ```
  x = array([[5,6], [3,4]])
  y = array([5,6])
  ```
- Case 3:

  ```
  x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
  y = np.array([5,6])
  ```

  gives

  ```
  x = [array([5,6]), [3,4]]
  y = [1,2]
  ```
- Case 4:

  ```
  x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
  y = np.array([5,6])
  ```

  gives

  ```
  x = array([[5,6], [3,4]])
  y = array([5,6])
  ```

It appears that the multiple assignment of lists is smarter (going through a temporary variable automatically) than the multiple assignment of Numpy arrays.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** It is not smarter afterall...

Comment: "It appears that the multiple assignment of lists is smarter (going through a temporary variable automatically) than the multiple assignment of Numpy arrays." -- How so? When assigning into a Numpy array, it turns that into part of the Numpy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only surprising cases here should be 2 & 4:

```
x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
y = np.array([5,6])  # or [5, 6]
```

giving

```
x = array([[5,6], [3,4]])
y = array([5,6])  # where did the 1 and 2 go?
```

Since the others are just swapping around data types, but keeping the same values.

What's different when using numpy is that `x[0]` returns a view, not a copy. So even writing out the temporary in the tuple assignment explicitly fails:

```
temp = x[0]
x[0] = y
y = temp
```

Because `temp` is a view that is always the same as `x[0]`, not a copy of the value of `x[0]` at that point in time.

To make this work for the numpy case, you should use `x[0],y = y,x[0].copy()`

Comment: Well, yes, 2 and 4 are the interesting ones but for completeness I added all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
x[0],y = y,x[0]
```

equals

```
t = x[0]
x[0] = y
y = t
```

As @Scimonster pointed out,

> When assigning into a Numpy array, it turns that into part of the
>   Numpy array.

So It's normal behavior.

Comment: It is not really true that these two code blocks are equal. Not temporary variable `t` is created; internally `y` and `x[0]` are pushed on to a stack, get flipped, and then are popped back off to be assigned. The two approaches can lead to different results.

Comment: @ajcr: Apart from the name `t` being clobbered, can you construct a case where the results do differ?

Comment: @Eric: I think I was mis-remembering something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566500/python-setting-two-variable-values-separated-by-a-comma-in-python/31566736#31566736) that I came across a while ago (which I see now doesn't involve a temporary variable). I think it should be possible to construct strange examples that mutate variables inplace during the assignment (so leaving a temporary variable unchanged) but until I can come up with something compelling, I'll retract my previous comment.