# List value swapping: What's the correct order and why?

Tags: python

For a list of integers, such as `A = [2, 10, -5]`, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 6, in <module>
    v, A[v-1] = A[v-1], v
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Code:

```
for i, v in enumerate(A):
    while 1<=v<=len(A) and v != A[v-1]:
        v, A[v-1] = A[v-1], v
```

but this works:

```
for i, v in enumerate(A):
    while 1<=v<=len(A) and v != A[v-1]:
        A[v-1], v = v, A[v-1]
```

Why the order of the swapping elements matters here? `v` is always being checked to be in bound.

Weirdly enough cannot reproduce a smaller example. But,
`A = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`
becomes an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you provide A and n?

Comment: You should refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally).

Comment: Don't reassign the iteration variable, `v`.

Comment: `i` is the index.  `v` the value. `A[i]` makes sense.  `A[v]` does not.

Comment: Note that your inner loop is a `while`, not an `if`.  Your list [6, 5, 4, 3, 2] gets stuck in the `while`.

Comment: @Prune: I got that `while` gets stuck here. And explanation comes from your ans below. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiserasif Can you describe in words what you want your code to do? Maybe give an example?

Comment: @Elias: put every integer in the corresponding position if the value falls in the valid range, otherwise skip. However, Prune's example clarifies what was bothering me, and what Tim had answered previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this with [2, 10, -5].
The detailed sequence of operations is

```
i, v = 0, 2
1 <= 2 ?     OK
2 != A[1] ?  OK ... stay in loop
    v, A[v-1] = 10, 2
    # This assignment breaks into ...
    v = 10
    A[10-1] = 2
    # ... and this second assignment is out of range.
```

If you switch the assignment order:

```
    A[v-1], v = 2, 10
    # This assignment breaks into ...
    A[2-1] = 2
    v = 10
```

In this case, your `while` conditions have properly guarded a legal assignment.

Note that you are *not* swapping list values; `v` is a local variable; it is *not* a reference to A[i].  For instance, in the above example, you do get `v=10`, but this does *not* affect the value of A[0].

Answer (score 7):

Python swaps the variables in the order provided, so `v` is assigned the value at `A[v-1]`, and then tries to reassign `A[v-1]` - but since v has been modified to be a list element, `v-1` is out of range of `A`.

Comment: Then, why the opposite doesn't cause the problem, i.e. `A[v-1]` set to `v` first, then `v` still gets the previous `A[v-1]` value from before the update.

Comment: Because you have an if statement ensuring that `v` is less than the length of the array, so `A[v-1]` is always set to a value that can index `A` in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

for i, v in enumerate(A):
    while 1<=v<=len(A) and v != A[v-1]:
        v, A[v-1] = A[v-1], v
```

You need to try running out your algorithm in your head:

Start:

i = 0, v = 6

v(6) is not between 1 and 5: next iteration

i = 1, v = 5, A[5-1] = 2

5 is between 1 and 5; v is not equal to 2: swap ->
v = 2; A[4] = 2

i = 1, v = 2, A[2-1] = 5

2 is between 1 and 5; v is not equal to 5: swap ->
v = 5; A[1] = 5

i = 1, v = 5, A[5-1] = 2

5 is between 1 and 5; v is not equal to 2: swap ->
v = 2; A[4] = 2

i = 1, v = 2, A[2-1] = 5

2 is between 1 and 5; v is not equal to 5: swap ->
v = 5; A[1] = 5

... and on and on

I don't think your algorithm makes sense. It's unclear why you are using the values in your list to index the list during your loop. I think this confusion about the index and values is at the root of your problem.