# How can I only use 2 variables in Java as with the Python code?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, while-loop, modulo

Can this Python code also be written in Java code? :

```
def gcd(a, b):
    # Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm.
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

print (gcd(210, 45))
```

This is what I've so far in Java code:

```
private static int gcd(int p, int q) {
    // Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm.
    int temp;
    while (q != 0) {
        temp = q;
        q = p % q;
        p = temp;
    }
    return p;
}

System.out.println(gcd(210, 45));
```

As you can see the Java code uses 3 variables whereas the Python code only uses 2 variables. I also want to use only 2 variables in the Java code and I want to keep the while loop and I don't want to use recursion.

Also why does Java need 1 more variable than the Python code? Except for the fact that the Python code uses a tuple.

Comment: Java doesn't have syntactic sugar for parallel assignment, so you need a temporary holding variable to do the multiple assignments sequentially without losing info.

Comment: Ok I was wrong, it uses the stack directly to swap the elements out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally

Comment: Well... you COULD use a little bit of trickery like so: `a = a %b; a += b; b = a - b; a -= b;`

Comment: @Dici That's actually cool. I always assumed it used a temp variable and had never looked under the hood at it. Good comment!

Comment: Haha yeah I was too quick to assume that too

Comment: @Turing85 Addition could overflow, XOR won't.

Comment: @pjs the overflow caused by the addition is reversed by the substraction.

Comment: @Dici Well, but how is *that* implemented? Looks like [with *two* temporary variables](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cadda52d974937069eeebea1cca4229e2bd400df/Python/ceval.c#L1534-L1538).

Comment: @Turing85 It's been years since I had to write any Java so I don't have a JVM lying around to check - have you actually tried that to confirm that overflow can be reversed by subtraction?  XOR is guaranteed to not overflow in the first place.

Comment: @superbrain ah nice find. So yeah, I guess there's no magic in this world

Comment: @pjs yes. Just make some pen&paper tests with a "maximum" value of 15 that overflows to -16. This works since integral types in java form a [mathematical ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Turing85 I agree that mathematically it's a ring.  I'm asking about whether the actual implementation conforms with the math abstraction.

Comment: @pjs yes. [`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE; Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE;`](https://ideone.com/y48sjb)

Comment: @Turing85 Meh, some test with some implementation is somewhat unsatisfying. Might want to link to [the specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2).

Comment: @superbrain well, I am not always in the mood to crawl the JLS ;) espeicially not if it's a section I am not familiar with. But yes. There you have it.

Comment: @Turing85 Me, neither. That's the only thing I know in the entire JLS. I despise Java :-)

Answer (score 2):

Two variables but you still have to swap.

```
public static int gcd(int r, int s) {
    while (s != 0) {
        r %= s;
        // swap them
        r ^= s;
        s ^= r;
        r ^= s;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Another possibility (but it wouldn't be Java) is to write a routine in `byte code`, store it in a `byte[]` array and execute it as a Java method.  If using the internal stack is okay as it is in Python, then it should be okay here.

Comment: I think these answers are a little out of topic, it's more about swapping values than actually managing to write a GCD with only two variables (which has little interest in itself)

Comment: The author of the question stated "I want to keep the while loop and I don't want to use recursion."

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is that Python has a tuple creation/decomposition feature, and Java does not.

As other answers have mentioned, you can do an integer swap with either xor or addition/subtraction.  However, I suspect that for performance platforms like C or Rust, this is a false economy, and this hack will not speed things up or decrease resource usage.  (If you're just in it for the challenge, though, it's legit, and probably the only solution)

Also, I don't think Java permits this trick for more general object references.

Comment: Doing a test run of 100M iterations of the same set of random numbers, the `single % op followed by three XOR's` is significantly faster than a `save, %, restore` version.  The latter took about 25% more time.  I reversed the order too.  Not a `JMH` test but the deltas were significant.  In both cases the GCD used the same while loop.  Would like to see someone test this with the harness.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about performance platforms like C++, not Python where most of the load is in the interpreter.  I will update and clarify my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is interesting to see that it helps in Java, thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1):

How about doing two steps in each loop iteration and not swapping at all?

```
private static int gcd(int p, int q) {
    // Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm.
    while (q != 0) {
        p %= q;
        if (p == 0)
           return q;
        q %= p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me If I'm wrong but, you can also do `gcd` operation using 2 variables in java.

```
private static int gcd(int p, int q) {
    // Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm.
    int temp;
    while (p != q) {
        if(p > q)
            p = p - q;
        else
            q = q - p;
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: This isn't directly equivalent because you can end up doing an absurd amount of subtractions (N) if one of the numbers is huge (N) and the other is small (e.g., 1). You need the modulo (`%`) to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python might be adding some synthetic sugar on top of the "exclusive or" operator. This is a bitwise operation to swap values of two different variables without using a temporary variable.

See Java example below:

```java
a = a^b;
b = a^b;
a = a^b;
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: Haha not bad. On the more general question of swapping, note this would only work for integers while Python's syntax applies to any type (in fact, it also works if `a` and `b` are of a different type)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the given examples, there is a well known algorithm to swap two integer variables `a` and `b` without the use of a third variable:

```
// given: two int-variables a and b
a += b;
b = a - b;
a -= b
// result: a and b have been swapped
```

If we now first calculate `a % b` and assign it to `a`, all that is left to do is to swap `a` and `b`:

```
// given: two int-variables a and b
a = a % b;
a += b;
b = a - b;
a -= b
// result: the new value of a is b, while the new value of b is a % b
```

This even works if the addition `a + b` overflows, since it is reversed by the subtractions.

---

As an aside: I see this as a code golf. Unless one is under heavy memory constraint, I would not advice to use this solution.