# Overwriting vs mutating pytorch weights

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to understand why I cannot directly overwrite the weights of a torch layer.
Consider the following example:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

net = nn.Linear(3, 1)
weights = torch.zeros(1,3)

# Overwriting does not work
net.state_dict()["weight"] = weights  # nothing happens
print(f"{net.state_dict()['weight']=}")

# But mutating does work
net.state_dict()["weight"][0] = weights  # indexing works
print(f"{net.state_dict()['weight']=}")

#########
# output
: net.state_dict()['weight']=tensor([[ 0.5464, -0.4110, -0.1063]])
: net.state_dict()['weight']=tensor([[0., 0., 0.]])
```

I'm confused since `state_dict()["weight"]` is just a torch tensor, so I feel I'm missing something really obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `net.state_dict()` first creates a `collections.OrderedDict` object, then stores the weight tensor(s) of this module to it, and returns the dict:

```py
state_dict = net.state_dict()
print(type(state_dict))    # <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

When you "overwrite" (it's in fact not an overwrite; it's *assignment* in python) this ordered dict, you reassign an int 0 to the key `'weights'` of this ordered dict. The data in that tensor is not modified, it's just not referred to by the ordered dict.

When you check whether the tensor is modified by:

```py
print(f"{net.state_dict()['weight']}")
```

a new ordered dict different from the one you have modified is created, so you see the unchanged tensor.

However, when you use indexing like this:

```py
net.state_dict()["weight"][0] = weights  # indexing works
```

then it's not assignment to the ordered dict anymore. Instead, the `__setitem__` method of the tensor is called, which allows you to access and modify the underlying memory inplace. Other tensor APIs such as `copy_` can also achieve desired results.

A clear explanation on the difference of `a = b` and `a[:] = b` when `a` is a tensor/array can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68978622/11790637

Answer (score 0):

I dont have torch installed right now,but try something like this from some saved code I have. I believe you need to make deep copys, like so

```
def zero_injection(initial_weights, trained_weights, mask):
    ''' zeros all weights and then injects in masked selection '''
    # copy the weights
    initial_weights_copy = copy.deepcopy(initial_weights.state_dict())
    trained_weights_copy = copy.deepcopy(trained_weights.state_dict())

    # set all the values to zero
    for key, value in initial_weights_copy.items():
        initial_weights_copy[key][initial_weights_copy[key] < 0] = 0
        initial_weights_copy[key][initial_weights_copy[key] > 0] = 0

    state_dict = {}
    # for each key
    for key, value in initial_weights_copy.items():
        # add the key
        state_dict[key] = []
        # if False, replace initial value with trained value
        state_dict[key] = initial_weights_copy[key].cuda().where(mask[key].cuda(), trained_weights_copy[key].cuda())

    return state_dict
```