# Why does Python swap the top two elements of the stack for swapping two variables?

Tags: python

The following Python code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a
```

compiles to the following Python bytecode:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             12 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

According to [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO), the instruction `ROT_TWO` swaps the order of the first two elements of the stack.

I'm having a hard time understanding why this is necessary.

My understanding is that, in order to swap `a` and `b`, you could just push `a`, then push `b`, then store the stacktop in `a`, then store the stacktop in `b`, achieving the variable swap. Something like this:

```
 1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             14 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             16 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why is this extra operation needed? Is there any advantage to doing it over the solution I suggested?

Comment: Will you write out the bytecode that you describe in your next-to-last paragraph?

Comment: I believe it's to guarantee that each side is evaluated from left to right.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047622/3799759.

Comment: The extra operation isn't needed here, where everything is a simple variable - but if `a` and `b` were actually something more complicated, that had side effects (`x[func1()], x[func2()]`, for example), the simplification would result in those side effects happening in a different order.

Comment: [evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) - right-hand-side first (left to right) then left-hand-side (left to right)

Comment: The evaluation order needs to be consistent and predictable - as mentioned in a comment below - `..swapping is just a special case of a larger idiom` - so it requires the extra operation to conform to the language spec. I've seen Q&A's here on SO regarding subtle things that happen with assignments because of the evaluation order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that, in order to swap a and b, you could just push a, then push b, then store the stacktop in a, then store the stacktop in b, achieving the variable swap.

You could, but that would read `a` first. `a, b = b, a` says to read `b` first.

That *usually* doesn't matter, but it can if you're executing this code in a very weird namespace, plus it would have implications for thread-safety and debugging.

Comment: Is it possible for threads to do this operation wrong in python, considering how threads still need the GIL?

Comment: @TomMcLean: The GIL protects the interpreter's internals from memory corruption. It doesn't automatically make Python code thread-safe. Another thread could still intervene between the variable read operations.

Comment: If either of the things on the right of the equals are function calls with side effects, execution order will matter even without threading troubles.  Remember that swapping is just a special case of a larger idiom.

Comment: I think my understanding of threads in python is wrong then, I always assumed that multithreading in python does not run concurrently, so the operation `a, b = b, a` will finish before another thread can do anything. Unless a and b were doing something weird like releasing the GIl during variable assignment. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: I guess like what @MarkRansom says, if b was `do_some_thread_task()` and a was another threading task, something weird could happen?

Comment: @TomMcLean: The GIL does not make `a, b = b, a` atomic. It will guarantee that, for example, threads won't intervene halfway through a variable read or write, but it won't guarantee that an entire line of Python code executes uninterrupted.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah, but if the reordering were safe for the special case of a variable swap, the peephole optimizer could have a case to optimize this. (It already optimizes out the tuple packing and unpacking that `a, b = b, a` would perform if executed literally as written.)